# A problem about equivalence class on ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $I$ an ideal of a ring $R$ and let $a,b\in R$. We define on $I$ the following equivalence relation
\begin{equation}
(a\equiv b\;\mod I)\iff a-b\in I,
\end{equation}
then
$$
\begin{align}
(1)&\;a+I=I\iff a\in I,\\
(2)&\;a+I=b+I\iff a-b\in I;\\
(3)&\;\text{Either}\;a+I=b+I\;\text{or}\; (a+I)\cap(b+I)=\emptyset.
\end{align}
$$
I know that these properties derive from the fact that $a+I=[a]_{\equiv}$, and that they are just a rewrite of the properties known for a general equivalence class, but I can not prove them by adapting them in this particular case. Can someone help me?

Comment: Haven't you studied before group theory?

Comment: A long time ago...

Comment: Can you do the first one?

Comment: @JackJ. Well, it is **exactly** the same as with (left) cosets of a subgroup...and if you do it with abelian group it is even a closer similarity

Comment: I do not know, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic proofs:

(1) Let $a+I=I$ for some $a\in R$. Then $a+0=a\in I$.
Conversely, let $a\in I$. Show the set equality $I=a+I$ by two inclusions. For instance, if $i\in I$, then $i = a + (i-a)\in a+I$, since  $i-a\in I$. The converse is similar.

(2) Let $a+I=b+I$. Then $a = a+ 0 = b+i$ for some $i\in I$ and so $a-b=i\in I$.
Conversely, let $a-b\in I$. Then $a-b=i$ for some $i\in I$. Show the set equality $a+I=b+I$ by two inclusions. For instance, let $c\in a+I$. Then for some $j\in I$, $c=a+j = b+ (i+j)\in b+I$, since $i+j\in I$. The converse is similar.

(3) Suppose $a+I \cap b+I\ne \emptyset$. Then there exists $c\in R$ with $c=a+i = b+j$ 
 for some $i,j\in I$. Then $a-b = j-i\in I$ and so by (2), $a+I=b+I$.

Answer (score 0):

1) suppose $a + I = I$, then $\forall i \in I$ there exists $j_{i} \in I$ such that $ i = a + j_{i}$
In particular, $0 \in I$, then $0 = a + j_{0}$ with $j_{0} \in I $

So $a = -j_{0} \in I$

Now, Suppose $a \in I$, then for each $i \in I$, $a - i \in I$

Then $i = a + (a - i) \in a + I$

So $I \subset a + I$.

And $a + I \subset I$, well, $I$ is a group then it is closed by addition

2) Suppose $a + I = b + I$ then $a + 0 = b + i$ for some $i \in I$

Then $a - b = i \in I$.

Now, suppose $a - b \in I$, then $I = (a-b) + I$ (we saw this in 1))

Then for each $i \in I$ there exists $j_{i} \in I$ such that $i = (a-b) + j_{i}$

Then $i + b = a + j_{i} \in a+I$, so $b + I \subset a + I$

We do the same thing using $b-a$ that is also in $I$

Then $i + a = b + j_{i} \in b +I$ then $a + I \subset b+I$

3) Suppose $a + I \not= b + I$ and $a + I \cap b + I \not= \emptyset$

Then there exists $i,j \in I$ such that $a + i = b + j$

Then $ a - b = j - i \in I$

Then $a + I = b + I$

Absurd.